# How to avoid repeating the parent classname in BEM cascade?

Tags: css, sass, bem

Example code (I know what it can be rewritten to avoid cascade, but I **write it as example**. This code is't real problem, what I can resolve in another way, it's just illustration):

```
.b-list {  
  //…

  &__item {
    //…
  }

  &__link {
    height: 4px;
    //…

    @at-root .b-list__item.-active & {
      height: 12px;       
    }     
  }
}
```

It is compiled to:

```
.b-list__link {
  height: 4px;
}

.b-list__item.-active .b-list__link {
  height: 12px;
}
```

I would like to change a selector `@at-root .b-list__item.-active &`
to something like `@at-root &__item.-active & {…}`
to avoid repeating the parent classname, but it doesn't work at Sass:

**This code doesn't work:**

```
.b-list {  
  //…

  &__item {
    //…
  }

  &__link {
    height: 4px;
    //…

    @at-root &__item.-active & {
      height: 12px;       
    }     
  }
}
```

So, there is a way to do what I want?

Comment: Would you be able to post your desired outputted CSS?

Comment: @asherstoppard I update post, tnx.

Comment: I would look at removing the specificity in your component and how you could achieve it with single classes using modifiers or using a state class (.is-active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways of acheiving the code you are looking for without an `@at-root` style function. However, as that was the original question the following should do the trick.

You can apply `&` to a variable and escape it as part of the class name later on through the nesting, as follows:

```
.b-list {
    $rootParent: &;
    &__link {
        height: 4px;

        #{$rootParent}__item.-active & {
            height: 12px;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems absolutely crazy but it works!

If you were looking to recreate the above in a more standardised way, I would definitely recommend the following:

```
.b-list {
    &__link {
        height: 4px;
    }

    &__item.-active &__link {
        height: 12px;
    }
}
```

It's also worth having a read through http://sass-guidelin.es/#selector-nesting, notably the section on BEM naming with the `&` current selector reference which states:

> While it might be anecdotal, generating new selectors from the current selector reference (&) makes those selectors unsearchable in the codebase since they do not exist per se.

Comment: I've always used a variant to this solution: I define a `$block` variable and set the root selector to `.#{$block} { /* &__elements */ }`. Never thought about setting it to `&` inside of the block, but I'm not sure which approach I like more.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to use a "root" variable with a block's name assigned to, yet I found it not very elegant, so have build a simple lib called [superbem](https://github.com/pittkost/superbem). It's a couple of Sass mixins that helps you stick to the BEM naming in a declarative way. Your example would look like this:

```
@include block(b-list) {
    @include element(link) {
        height: 4px;
    }

    @include element(item) {
        &.-active {
            @include element(link) {
                height: 12px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution messes with source mapping. When debugging styles, this can get very confusing and counter productive. Element UI uses this and it is a pain to find the origin code line of a style, because the displayed line is always the line of the mixin.